# Word problem and quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, quotient-group, combinatorics-on-words

Let $G$ be given by the [group presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) $G = \langle a,b \mid S \rangle$, where $S = \{aa,bbb\}$. The formal definition of $G$ is:

> Let $F$ be the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) on $\{a,b\}$. Let $H$ be the [conjugate
>   closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_closure) of $S$, i.e. $H$ is the subgroup of $F$ generated by
>   $\{fsf^{-1} : f \in F, s \in S\}$. Then we can define the quotient
>   group $G = F/H$.

Let $x,y \in F$ be words consisting of only letters $a, b$. Using the formal definition of $G$ above, how can we show that if $x=y$ in $G$ (i.e. $xH = yH$), then there is a finite sequence of operations changing $x$ to $y$ where in each operation we either add/remove an $aa$ or add/remove a $bbb$ to $x$?

**Thoughts:** We can write $y^{-1}x = \text{reduce}(f_1 s_1 f_1^{-1} f_2 s_2 f_2^{-1} \dots f_k s_k f_k^{-1})$, where $f_i \in F$, and $s_j \in S' = \{aa,bbb,a^{-1}a^{-1},b^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}\}$. Here reduce($w$) is the reduction of $w$ in the free group by cancellation of consecutive $a,a^{-1}$ or $b,b^{-1}$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

**Edit:** Can we also show this holds for arbitrary $S$? For example, $S = \{aa,bbb,ababab\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might not find this answer satisfactory, because it involves more general abstract concepts.

But (I think) what you are asking is equivalent to asking whether the monoid defined by the given presentation embeds into the group defined by the same presentation.

The answer to this is yes in your example, and also in the example in your edit (and in any example in which there is exists $k>0$ with $x^k \in S$ for all generators $x$), because in these examples the generators, and hence all elements in the monoid defined by the presentation, manifestly have 2-sided inverses, and so this monoid is itself a group.

In this situation, the monoid/group $M$ defined by the presentation is naturally isomorphic to the group $G$ defined by the same presentation. To see this, let $X$ be the set of generators of $M$. Then an element of $G$ consists of equivalence classes of words over $X \cup X^{-1}$, but by assumption, each $x^{-1}$ is equal in $G$ to a word $\bar{x}$ over $X$, and so the same applies to any word over $X \cup X^{-1}$. We need to show that two words over $X$ are equivalent in the monoid $M$ if and only if they are equivalent in the group $G$. Clearly equivalence in $M$ implies equivalence in $G$. For the converse, if two such words $v,w$ are equivalent in $G$, then we can transform $v$ to $w$ by inserting or deleting defining relators of $M$ or strings $xx^{-1}$ or $x^{-1}x$ for $x \in X$. To move from $v$ to $w$ in $M$, whenever we insert $xx^{-1}$ of $x^{-1}x$, we instead insert or delete $x\bar{x}$ or $\bar{x}x$, both of which are relators of $M$ by assumption.

But the answer to your general question is no, and the simplest example is $\langle a,b \mid ab \rangle$. In the group defined by this presentation the word $ba$ defines the identity element, but that is not true in the monoid, so the word $ba$ cannot be reduced to the empty word by inserting and removing strings $ab$.

Note that the elements of this monoid have normal form $\{ b^ia^j : i,j \ge 0 \}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is indeed very surprising to me that this is not true for some $S$. I'm still trying to understand, how does the fact that the monoid presentation is a group relate to the group presentation? Also, is the "normal form" the elements of the monoid presentation? Do you know of any good reference on these concepts?

Comment: The normal form just  means that every element in the monoid can be represented as $b^ia^j$ for unique values of $i,j$ with $i \ge 0$, $j \ge 0$. For your original question, the group is a free product of $C_2$ and $C_3$, and I think probably the most efficient way to prove it is to learn the basic theory of free products of groups, which is not too hard. Then the question becomes relatively easy.

Comment: Do you know how we would prove: the monoid presentation is a group $\implies$ the equivalence classes coincides with the cosets of the group presentation? Also, for the $\langle a,b \mid ab \rangle$ case, if we allow removal/addition of $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ as well as $ab$, is it still not true that such equivalence classes coincide with the cosets of the group presentation?

For example, Lemma 1.2.1 [here](http://ahmetsinancevik.com/pdfler/mythesis.pdf) indicates the last statement is true, but I have a huge doubt about it.

Comment: For your first question, I have added a (not completely formal) proof to my answer above. I don't understand your second question. If you mean the monoid $\langle a,b \mid ab \rangle$, then the string $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is not defined, but if you mean the group presentation, then clearly $ab = 1$ is equivalent to $b^{-1}a^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the proof, it is very nice. I was referring to the group presentation $\langle a,b \mid ab\rangle$, but I didn't know that the equivalence classes also includes transformations by adding/deleting strings $xx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}x$, in which case indeed $ab$ can be transformed to $b^{-1}a^{-1}$. I think my final doubt goes back to the topic of quotient groups: how do we show that the equivalence classes of group $G$ by such transformations correspond to the cosets of the quotient group $H$ as defined?

Comment: It is a bad idea to keep asking more and more questions in comments. Perhaps you should ask a new question?